# Default gateway changes after network/system reboot

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I have the problem that my server does not take over my gateway (10.0.0.1) from the configuration "/etc/network/interfaces".
After a restart it always changes to the old gateway (192.168.178.1) I had before.

```
## /etc/network/interfaces ##

# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet static
 address 10.0.0.5
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 10.0.0.1
```

```
## Kernel IP routing table ##

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

```
## IP´s ##

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:30:05:cb:cc:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.5/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.178.5/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd54:c52a:6301:1:4fcd:6215:d975:ba24/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 2591827sec preferred_lft 604627sec
    inet6 2003:dc:f72d:d400:3941:34f8:51c0:e2aa/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 7027sec preferred_lft 1043sec
    inet6 fe80::3067:148d:bae7:e488/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Sorry for my bad english...

Best regards,

ZeRoNiX

Comment: Do you have any files in the `/etc/network/interfaces.d` directory?

Comment: No, this dir is empty.

Comment: I forgot to say that the server additionally is getting a wrong ip.

Comment: is dhcp enabled? could it be that you use ubuntu 18 or later?

Comment: Iam using Debian 10, and no DHCP is disabled.